# selenium - trying to populate 1st iframe on page but finds 2nd

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to populate first iframe on my page. It has 2 iframes on it. I am using the following code but it keeps populating the 2nd iframe for reasons unknown to me.

```
        List<IWebElement> iframeList = Client.WebDriver.FindElementsByXPath(".//iframe");
        IWebDriver overDrive = Client.WebDriver.Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeList[0]);
        IWebElement bodyLogin = overDrive.FindElement(By.TagName(("body")));
        bodyLogin.SendKeys("My Text Message");
```

Comment: What if you switch to index 1 instead?

Comment: same result. I stepped through it to make sure.